# How to switch interfaces in Laravel whilst developing

Tags: php, laravel-5

I am building a `Laravel 5.2` App that will connect to a database that I don't have available to me whilst developing (it is a legacy database that I cannot install locally).

What is the cleanest way in Laravel to build my application so that I can develop using one interface, and then switch over to another when I push my project to the live environment?

In the past, I've had 2 classes, both of which have the same functions, and then in a configuration file, I would say which class it uses. Just wandering if there is a better way using Laravel? Or if there is a way of doing this already baked in?

Comment: By *switch interface* you mean switch to the other database or a real interface? Can you give example of what you want the end result to be?

Comment: So when I am developing locally, I would have a stubbed out class that returns hardcoded values so that I can continue developing. For example, a function called `getOrders` would return a hardcoded array when developing locally, but when I deploy it to live, I want it to use the real database, not the stubbed out class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way I can think of achieving this is to switch the instance of the dependency injection when you're on *local* and *production* environment.

```
class ControllerExample 
{
    public function index( SomeInterface $data ) 
    {
        //...
    }
}
```

So in this example the controller *index* method needs *SomeInterface* which would be injected automatically. For *local* development you can resolve this interface to your stub class and for *production* you can switch to the real class. You can do this by registering the binding of the interface in the *app / Providers / AppServiceProvider.php* in the *register()* method:

```
if ($this->app->environment() == 'local') {
    $this->app->when('App\Your\ControllerExample')
        ->needs('App\SomeInterface')
        ->give('App\YourStubbedClass');
} else {
    $this->app->when('App\Your\ControllerExample')
        ->needs('App\SomeInterface')
        ->give('App\YourRealClassWorkingWithTheRealDatabase');
}
```

What this basically does is when your env is *local* the dependency in your controller will be resolved with the stub class, otherwise on other envs it will be the real class.

Comment: Fantastic! I'll give this a go and report back.

Comment: Exactly what I wanted. Thanks!